# Функция вызывается сама на python

Tags: функции, visual-studio-code, python-3.8, декоратор

Почему-то функция вызывается сама,хотя я не написал *hello_html()* или *print(hello_html())*.

```
def decorator(func):
    print("Decorator started...")
    func()
    print("Decorator finished")
def dec_htlml(func):
    print("<h1>+func()+</h1>")
def hello():
    print("Hello world!")
hello_html=decorator(hello)
```

Вывод:

```
Decorator started...
Hello world!
Decorator finished.
```

А если последнюю строчку убрать то ничего не выводит, объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит.

Comment: Но ты же написал `func()`

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что ты вызываешь функцию из кода декоратора, вместо, собственно, декорации.

Попробуй так:

```
def decorator(func):
    def inner():
        print("Decorator started...")
        func()
        print("Decorator finished")
    return inner

def hello():
    print("Hello world!")

hello_html=decorator(hello)
hello_html()
```